# Connecting to SQL through R in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, odbc

I am trying to connect to our SQL database how we usually connect to our DB in R. Locally we use the following script, both with and without the port number (since I only need 1433 which is default):

```
con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                    DRIVER="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                    SERVER="Server,port",
                    DATABASE="Database",
                    UID="User",
                    PWD="Password")
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me the following error.

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
> Traceback:

I opened up an environment in Python and used pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
r'SERVER=Server;'
r'DATABASE=Database;'
r'UID=User;'
r'PWD=Password;'
r'PORT=1433;'
)
```

And I was able to connect and run a query with no problem. Any advice on this? The drivers are present in the compute instance, so not sure why I'm unable to connect.

When I ran an R script through the terminal I got this error.

> sudo Rscript connectSQLserver.R
> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
> Execution halted

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error is correct - `PORT` is not an SQL Server ODBC connection string attribute. If you wish to specify a port the convention is to include it in the server attribute, i.e.: `SERVER=yourServerNameOrIpAddressHere,portNumber;`

Comment: FYI, "port" for SQL Server defaults to 1433, you should not need to specify it at all. Also, for clarity on AlwaysLearning's point, quote the server and port, so `SERVER="ipaddr,1433"`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah tried your method by adding port number after a comma in the server attribute i.e 1.2.3.4.5,1433 but as r2evans mentioned I just need to use the default port. Unfortunately even not specifying gives me the same issue.

Comment: @nowyouredoingit, please [edit] your question with the corrected connection expression.

Comment: Your args look correct, consider trying some non-default options? e.g., `trustservercertificate="yes"`, perhaps `encrypt="yes"`. I think upper/lower case does not matter. Also, make sure your `Server` is a real name and/or real IP address; if you are port-forwarding from a local ssh connection (perhaps unlikely, but ... it's how I connect to my DBs), windows does not like `localhost`, preferring `127.0.0.1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect my sql database in ML studio using below R script:

```
con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       DRIVER="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                       SERVER="<serverName>",
                       DATABASE="<databaseName>",
                       UID="<userName>",
                       PWD="<password>",
                       port = 1433 )
```

It connected successfully without any error:

[image]

Make sure allow remote connections to the sql server

[image]

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection Traceback

Above error may be cause of Invalid connection string or network issue. Once check the connection string and check network connectivity, check sql server configuration, check firewall settings.

Comment: I'll look into this, but my question is I can connect remotely using the same IP address for the server in Python in the same compute instance. So would assume it's already set up to allow remote connection is already set up? Would there be any potential reason behind this? Thank you!

Comment: You are running r script in Azure ML studio once check Allow Azure services and resources to access this server is enabled or not? [image](https://i.imgur.com/9ffnIoV.png) for reference.